# ClickHouse Unknown Codec Family Error on Version Update

Tags: database, olap, clickhouse

I have been working on a three node ClickHouse Cluster with a Table created using **ReplicatedMergeTree**. I recently updated one of its nodes from version **18.14.2** to **19.3.7**. However, after the upgrade, I could not establish a connection with the upgraded node as the data did not sync up.

The ClickHouse error logs are as follows.

```
(StorageReplicatedMergeTree): DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::<lambda(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr&)>: Code: 432, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown codec family code : 130, Stack trace:

0. clickhouse-server(StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x16) [0x5d9fdf6]
1. clickhouse-server(DB::Exception::Exception(std::string const&, int)+0x1f) [0x2ceb79f]
2. clickhouse-server(DB::CompressionCodecFactory::get(unsigned char) const+0x185) [0x5af35b5]
3. clickhouse-server(DB::CompressedReadBufferBase::readCompressedData(unsigned long&, unsigned long&)+0x911) [0x5af0e31]
4. clickhouse-server(DB::CompressedReadBuffer::nextImpl()+0x26) [0x5aef7b6]
5. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPartChecksums::read_v3(DB::ReadBuffer&)+0x834) [0x5738604]
6. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPartChecksums::read_v4(DB::ReadBuffer&)+0xb2) [0x5738fd2]
7. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPartChecksums::read(DB::ReadBuffer&, unsigned long)+0x28) [0x5739f68]
8. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPartChecksums::read(DB::ReadBuffer&)+0x94) [0x573a114]
9. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPart::loadChecksums(bool)+0x119) [0x572f6b9]
10. clickhouse-server(DB::MergeTreeDataPart::loadColumnsChecksumsIndexes(bool, bool)+0x39) [0x57338a9]
11. clickhouse-server(DB::DataPartsExchange::Fetcher::fetchPart(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int, DB::ConnectionTimeouts const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool, std::string const&)+0xdde) [0x56d955e]
12. clickhouse-server() [0x567a556]
13. clickhouse-server(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::fetchPart(std::string const&, std::string const&, bool, unsigned long)+0x7a9) [0x569c379]
14. clickhouse-server(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::executeFetch(DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry&)+0x999) [0x569ebf9]
15. clickhouse-server(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::executeLogEntry(DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry&)+0x9f) [0x56a3c9f]
16. clickhouse-server() [0x56a4610]
17. clickhouse-server(DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeQueue::processEntry(std::function<std::shared_ptr<zkutil::ZooKeeper> ()>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry>&, std::function<bool (std::shared_ptr<DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry>&)>)+0x3e) [0x57aadfe]
18. clickhouse-server(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()+0x192) [0x5678b62]
19. clickhouse-server(DB::BackgroundProcessingPool::threadFunction()+0x396) [0x56d3b86]
20. clickhouse-server() [0x56d4484]
21. clickhouse-server(ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::worker(std::_List_iterator<std::thread>)+0x199) [0x5da8aa9]
22. clickhouse-server() [0x65ce86f]
23. /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fb7b43ffe25]
24. /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fb7b3c2334d]
```

**Edit 1:**

Upgrading to 19.4.3.11 fixed this error. However, now continuously getting the following error and still unable to establish connection with the Server.

> (StorageReplicatedMergeTree): DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Null pointer: _pInstance in file "/home/centos/clickhouse-rpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/ClickHouse-19.4.3.11-stable/contrib/poco/Util/include/Poco/Util/Application.h", line 457

**Edit 2:**

Found that the above is another bug in ClickHouse v19.4.3.11 - https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/5005

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exceptions, need to execute query below on failed nodes (see [github: DB::Exception: Unknown codec family code : 4](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/4467)):

```sql
SYSTEM DROP MARK CACHE
```

Comment: I am unable to connect via the ClickHouse Client to the Server. Without the connection, I won't be able to run the query.

Comment: Try to restart node and run CH client as just CH server up.

Comment: This is the error I am getting while trying to run CH Client.

`Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (mynodeip:9000)`

Comment: The server is being starting, please try to run this command several times.

Comment: The error has been repeating itself for hours. The server is still yet to start and not able to get the connection. Is there a way to manually delete the corrupt parts ?

Comment: Let's try the next: 1) stop CH on each node of cluster (*sudo service clickhouse-server stop*) 2) run CH just on one  node (*service clickhouse-server start*) 3) try to run *clickhouse-client* on this node